# Choose k vectors from n vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

Suppose there are a matrix of three row vectors

```
A = [1,2;
     1,3;
     2,3]
```

I would like to create a new matrix B which draws two vectors from A with repetitions, and there are 3^2 possible combinations. Some simple implementation is as follows:

```
For i = 1:3
    c = A(i,:);
    for j=1:3
        d = A(j,:);
        B = [c;d];
    end
end
```

But, in general, if I need to choose `k` vectors from `n` vectors, what is the more general way to write such loop? It's difficult to continue write loop using `i`, `j`, ... I guess. Thanks!

Comment: It is better [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) for this to pick `k` uniformly distributed numbers in the range `1:n` (with replacement)

```
k = 2;
n = size(A,1);
rowIdx = randi(n,k)
B = A(rowIdx,:)
```

Answer (score 1):

For sampling at random, matlab has [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
rowIdx = randsample( size(A,1), k, true );
B = A(rowIdx,:);
```

Comment: Thanks! but maybe I am wrong, if I use such random sampling, it returns me only one instance? How can I keep track of all possible combinations of the k draws from n vectors? In this case, there are 9 possibilities, how can I find out all 9 cases?

Comment: @ximu then you need to use `nchoosek` function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all previous suggestions. 
In the end I figure out what I want is called permutations with repetitions. The matlab function [permun](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-permn-v--n--k-/content/permn.m) from file exchange solves my problem.